# Concatenar checkbox

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una duda, la cual es la siguiente:
Estoy haciendo un cuestionario pero la dinámica es la siguiente:

1.- ¿Qué ciudades has visitado?
[] México
[] Brasil
[] África

La duda que tengo es cómo concateno las opciones que elijan en `JavaScript`, esa pregunta o preguntas están en un formulario de `HTML` pero quiero concatenar si eligen una o varias opciones para mandarlas como respuesta de esa pregunta.

La idea es que si eligen México y Brasil, se mande como respuesta: `México || Brasil` o algo que las separe pero que vengan las respuestas juntas en un `String` o algo para que mande esa respuesta concatenada.

Saludos.

Comment: No te recomiendo manejarlo concatenado, estarías haciendo una mala práctica, aunque sí funciona  claro está hahaha. Así como lo tratas de hacer basta con un poco de código javascript o con jQuery para más rápido con el que cachas el submit del formulario, compruebas cuáles son los input type checkbox que están seleccionados y los recorres y as concatenando en una variable sus value, al final la variable se la asignas como valor a un input type hidden y allá en el servidor lo recibes y le haces un concat.Repito, mejor ponles el mismo nombre a los checkbox  y en el server los guardas en array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elementoPaises = document.getElementById('paises')
var paisesElegidos = []

function elegirPais(element){
    if (element.checked) {
        paisesElegidos.push(element.value)
    }else{
        paisesElegidos.splice( paisesElegidos.indexOf( element.value ), 1 )
    }
    elementoPaises.innerHTML = paisesElegidos.join(', ')
}
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Mexico" onclick="elegirPais(this)"> Mexico</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Brasil" onclick="elegirPais(this)"> Brasil</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Africa" onclick="elegirPais(this)"> Africa</p>

<p>Has visitado <span id="paises"></span></p>
```

Comment: +1 - Por ser el único que usa javascript.. si explicarías un poco el código / la idea... mejor

Comment: * Vanilla javascript

Comment: Facil, al hacer click en un checkbox, ejecutas la funcion `elegirPais(this)`, el `this` que pasas por parametro, es el objeto del elemento (el checkbox como tal)... etonces lo que haces en la funcion es preguntar si el elemento esta checked, lo añade a un array, y si no, lo quita... despues se le hace un `.join()` al array para que lo convierta e un string, y lo imprime e el elemento co el id`#paises`

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z - Edita tu respuesta y pega tu comentario/explicación

Comment: chamo dejame codear tranquilo!! estoy ocupado, si le funciona que lo use!!ya fin.

Answer (score 0):

Basta con que pongas el atributo "name" igual en los tres y en el lado del servidor los recibes como normalmente los recibirías pero los guardarías en un arreglo, lista, etc y ya.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacerlo, que tratará al conjunto de checkboxes como un array, es ponerle a todos el mismo nombre, seguido de corchetes [].

En ese caso, el request le pasa un arreglo de países al backend.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#probar').on('click',function() {
   console.log(jQuery('#checkboxes').serialize());
  });
});
```

```css
label {
 clear:both;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="checkboxes">

<label><input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" value="mexico"/>México</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" value="chile"/>Chile</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" value="colombia"/>Colombia</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="pais[]" value="argentina"/>Argentina</label>

<input type="submit" id="probar" value="enviar"  />

</form>
```

PD: Ninguna de las opciones es  una ciudad, pero eso son detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Este código te devolverá un array con los nombres de países seleccionados. Podrás usar ese array para las operaciones que necesites: sea mostrarlos en tu html, sea enviarlos a tu servidor a través de un archivo php

```js
<!--jQuery-->

$(function() {
      $("#btn-paises").click( function()
      {
     var arrPaises = $('input[name="paises"]:checked').map(function() 
        {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get();
            console.log(arrPaises);  
            alert(arrPaises);  

     });
    });
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>Países visitados:</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" name="paises" value="Brasil"> Brasil</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" name="paises" value="México"> México</label><br>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" name="paises" value="Colombia"> Colombia</label><br>
<button id="btn-paises">Enviar Países</button>
<div id="datos"></div>
```

---

**Ejemplo de resultado:**
Obtendrás un array con los valores de los checkbox seleccionados, con los cuales podrás operar para tus necesidades.

```
["Brasil", "México"]
```

Leer los valores del array es muy fácil, por ejemplo:

```
$.each(arrPaises, function (k, v) { 
  console.log('País: '+v); 
});
```

El nombre de cada país tendrá el valor v dentro del bucle.

Si quieres enviarlo al servidor a través de PHP le puedes pasar el array completo, sin leerlo, a tu PHP.

Es una manera limpia y ordenada de proceder. Todo dependerá de tus necesidades.